# Null byte injection to run PHP?

Tags: php, xss, null-byte-injection

A website accepts form input and outputs it to the screen, but replaces every `<?` to `<--?` turning them to comments.

Let's say I POST the following:

```
<?php echo "xy"; /* arbitrary php code */
```

and I want to get it running. Is there any way to inject something between the `<` and `?` characters that gets skipped during php parsing?

Answer (score 6):

No. PHP will parse the *php file* looking for either `<?php`, `<?` or `<?=` (depending on the value of `short_tags`)

However, outputting `<?php` to the screen would *not* execute code. It would need to have been evaluated (eg. saved to a .php file in the server that you then run). This form is probably vulnerable to XSS, though.

Comment: Yes, I injected other DOM elements and javascript to this page, sad to hear I can't go further. Thanks.